# Code examples for aggregates roots and aggregates

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, aggregate, aggregateroot

I am trying to understand how to use Aggregate roots and Aggregates, but I can't find any concrete information or examples on it.

For example I have the following three Entities:

1. Survey
2. QuestionGroup
3. Question

A **Question** entity cannot exist without a **Survey** or **QuestionGroup** entity. All Questions belong to a QuestionGroup, so my understanding is

> QuestionGroup is the Aggregate root of Question

A QuestionGroup also cannot exist without being part of a Survey, so

> Survey is Aggregate root to QuestionGroup

It seems like the above is a case of nested Aggregate roots.

**Q1.** How do you actually create an Aggregate root and Aggregate in c#? What does that look like in code? Do you use inner classes or does the Aggregate root hold a reference? I can't find any good examples on this.

**Q2.** Taking it one step further how code a nested Aggregate root?

Thx!

Comment: Take a look at [effective aggregate design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011) for guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Survey is the aggregate root.

```
class Survey {
    public IEnumerable<QuestionGroup> QuestionGroups { get ... }
}
class QuestionGroup {
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get ... }
}
class Question {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be more complicated than that... The reason being was I thought you had to somehow "prevent" developers from accessing the classes contained in the Aggregate roots

Comment: @chobo it *is* more complicated than that. You're supposed to control (not necessarily prevent) access to the parts that make up the aggregate root. The most important concept is that if you were to delete the root, then all of the parts should be deleted as well. This example is over-simplified and incomplete imo